# not able to update the default value using pdo

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

Friends , i am not able to update the status of the table from my editpage where i passed my id from the previous page and by using that id i want to update my table which is not happening .Since i have kept Pending as default from my table is that the reason value in not updating ??

It executes the query but does not update my database

aadhar_card is the table.

```
session_start();

$aadhar_id=$_POST['aadhar_id'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $status=$_POST['status'];
    $update=$db->prepare('update aadhar_card  set status=:status where aadhar_id=:aadhar_id');
    $update->bindValue(':status',$status);
    $update->bindValue(':aadhar_id',$aadhar_id);
    $update->execute();
    if($update)
        header('location:formAdmin.php');//it is redirecting but not updating
    else
        echo 'not happening';
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-5">
                    <select class="col-md-5" style="height: 5%;" name="status">

                      <option value="Accepted" >Accepted</option>

                      <option value="Pending" >Pending</option>

                      <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>


                    </select>

                    <input type="submit" value="Update Status" name="submit">
                  </div>
                  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

i am getting the correct  id from the previous page and i have passed it using hidden fields but not able to update."pending" is the default value in the table as soon as the form is filled by default "pending" value will be allocated to the form as the status and then it is changed here by admin from pending to accepted or rejected.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the correct values for `$status` and `$aadhar_id` values to your query ? What happens when you do `var_dump($_POST)` to check the value of POST variables? Also, do you have error reporting turned on for your PHP code ?

Comment: You have `$_POST['aadhar_id']`, but there's no form field with `name="aadhar_id"`.

Comment: Could you also be missing a opening php tag `<?php` before `session_start();` ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 If that were the problem none of the code would run.

Comment: @Barmar yes. You are right about that.

Comment: no sir everything is inside the <?php tag and passed aadhar_id from the previous page and by doing var_dump its showing me the aadhar_id